# How to create dropdown menu in AngularJs 2 Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to create dropdown menu in AngularJs 2 Javascript?
I have watched alot of tutorials but there is only available for Typescript. i need it in Javascript. Please help.

```
    (function(app) {
  app.HeaderComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
      selector: 'header',
      template:
      `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
            </button>
            <a href="" class=" navbar-brand">
              <span class="brandname">Slant<sub>&nbsp;AngulatJS</sub></span>
            </a>  
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="dashboarddiv">
                <a href="#" class="dashboard">&nbsp;Dashboard</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href=""></a></li>
              <li>
                <div [hidden]="submitted">
                  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #Header="ngForm">
                    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!Header.form.valid"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></button>
                  </form>
                </div>
                <div [hidden]="!submitted">
                  <button (click)="submitted=false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></button>
                  <h2>You submitted</h2>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">Name</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9  pull-left">rrr</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">Alter Ego</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 pull-left">r</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">Power</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9 pull-left">r</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </nav>`
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {
        this.submitted = false;
      },
      onSubmit: function() {
        this.submitted = true;
      },

    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

I have tried this. but it creates div hide and show. I want dropdown menu in navigation bar.

[This is the result of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4VxI.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about how to ask good questions. Your question doesn't provide enough information about what you try to accomplish. It also doesn't demonstrate what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: I have edited the question. please help